# UWP Is the size of Roaming ApplicationData the file Actual Size or Size on Disk?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

The following link explains the size of the maximum data allowed to roam between devices, and also that once the 100KB limit is exceeded, ALL roaming functionality is stopped.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingsettings.aspx

Does anyone happen to know if the size of the file being roamed is the actual file size, or the size of the file on disk.

Just in case that isn't clear, I'm writing a JSON file with settings and data that is 736 bytes of actual space, which turns into 4KB of disk space.  Which one of these values does Microsoft use for calculating available space remaining?

And, is there a framework anyone knows of for querying the amount of space left?  I know Microsoft doesn't offer native support for that functionality, but thought there might be a third party solution.

Many thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size on disc only applies to your machine. Just the bare bytes are transmitted through the web.

You can just check the size of the settings file. It's located in your apps settings folder (%home%\AppData\Local\Packages\%appid%\Settings).

(But not accessible from the apps Sandbox...)

On the other hand, you know you can only store about 100k characters including keys, so if you really get anywhere near this, you should consider a different roaming mechanism or the kind of data you store there.

Comment: That's excellent, thank you!  With only bare bytes, 100K is more than enough.